# Office365 NTLM authentication

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, ntlm

Can I authenticate credentials with Office365 based on NTLMv2.

Microsoft describes on [*Authentication and EWS in Exchange*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/authentication-and-ews-in-exchange) that clients can authenticate with Exchange based on NTLM, but My program connects to outlook.office365.com to authenticate based on NTLM Office365 replies Basic-Authentication.

Does anyone know what's the problem? Or how can authenticate Office365 with NTLM authentication technique?

Comment: Right at the top of the linked page, it says: " 
NTLM (Exchange on-premises only) 
"

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot. O365 uses modern claims based auth, so WS* and SAML.  Possibly OAUTH or OPENID too.

If you have on-prem AD, ADFS, you can probably auth to that, and get a token to pass to O365.

Answer (score 1):

According the article you provided, it seems NTLM authentication is only available for Exchange on-premises servers.